# MouseLeftButtonUp does not fire for ScrollViewer in WPF control template

Tags: c#, wpf

In WPF and C# I am trying to set up a mouse drag scrolling feature for a ScrollViewer contained within a control template for a document viewer. The problem: I have not been able to get the MouseLeftButtonEvent to fire.

It is basically the default DocumentViewer template, with a few features modified. Here is an outline in XAML:

```
<Style x:Key="DocumentViewerStyle1" BasedOn="{x:Null}" TargetType="{x:Type DocumentViewer}">
<!--...—>
    <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{x:Null}" />  <!--So does not mess up right click, if I use that-->
<!--...-->
    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DocumentViewer}">
<!--...-->
        <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost" CanContentScroll="True"
            IsHitTestVisible="True" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
            Grid.Row="1" Loaded ="OnScrollViewerLoaded" />
        <DockPanel Grid.Row="1" >
<!-...-->
</ControlTemplate>
</Style>
```

I use the following in code behind so that I can access the ScrollViewer. If one changes “Left” to “Right” in the method below, it works to perfection, but of course with the right mouse button rather than the left.

```
    public partial class PrintPreview : Window
    {
        private ScrollViewer nomad;
```

etc. and

```
private void OnScrollViewerLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    nomad = (ScrollViewer)sender;
    nomad.AddHandler(MouseLeftButtonDownEvent, new MouseButtonEventHandler(OnMouseButtonDown), true);
    nomad.AddHandler(MouseLeftButtonUpEvent, new MouseButtonEventHandler(OnMouseButtonUp), true);
    nomad.AddHandler(MouseMoveEvent, new MouseEventHandler(OnMouseMove), true);
}
```

The OnMouseButtonUp event handler, for example, is

```
private void OnMouseButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    nomad.Cursor = Cursors.IBeam;
    nomad.ReleaseMouseCapture();
}
```

Have tried various things found here: No help from using Preview events for my three mouse events. No help from setting Focusable="False" for the ScrollViewer, or for setting a Background for it. Any suggestions?  Thanks!

Comment: The first thing I always make sure is to explicitly set the Background to a non Null value (e.g. Brushes.Transparent) or add a border behind all component in your control template with defined Background, otherwise mouse events won't fire

Comment: I tried further experimentation with Background after seeing you thoughts, but it made no difference. Thanks, though.